# Emails disappearing from sent items

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, exchange-2013

I have a user who is experiencing one of the strangest things I've seen. Every x number of emails disappears completely from Outlook. This is an exchange environment.

What I can rule out

- An entire mailbox search finds nothing
- I've configured mailbox auditing to track *Move, MoveToDeletedItems, SoftDelete, HardDelete* for Owner, Delegates and Admin - Nothing found
- Not done by any erroneous rules
- Not being removed by any Outlook add-ins

Has anyone any thoughts as this is worse than trying to find  a needle in a haystack.

Comment: By "every x" do you mean 1 in every x, or that after x all x disappear?

Comment: Did you try [Repair an Office application](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repair-an-Office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b)?

Comment: Have you ruled out work colleagues who think they're hilarious and have access to her password and Outlook Web Access?  Have you also definitely ruled out her not actually clicking the send button? Are they in her "outbox" waiting to be sent but not sent *yet*?

Comment: @DavidPostill every 1 in X - could send 10 then 1 would disappear, could send 2 and both would disappear. No commonality between the chain. Could it be a corrupt Outlook install you're suggesting ? I'll admit I haven't done it only because the behavior is so strange and it's not showing on OWA either.

Comment: @Mokubai, thought that but from the exchange auditing I can't find any softDelete or HardDelete entries in the audit logs. Also, no-one else has the p/w - I asked and it was recently changed. They only disappear from the sent items folder, they are definitely there before going missing - I've seen it happen.

Comment: I see you checked rules, but have you disabled the rules? And have you checked the rules in OWA?

Comment: @music2myear, yes I have also completely deleted rules from Outlook and the OWA.

Answer (score 0):

Any POP3 client or IMAP client for this effected mailbox?

It seems strange if the disappear message is irregularity. To narrow down this issue, try to remove all clients from this mailbox, and leave OWA only. (it should be nice to new a test account if we can reproduce it)

If it's fine in OWA, then we cloud use exclusive method to narrow it. (start to configure Outlook or ActiveSync client one by one)

If the issue persists in OWA, open IIS to compare the client connection and also the action in Audit log.

Answer (score 0):

we have the same issue and have determined that our email retention policy is removing the messages from the sent folder.  When the template is used, the created date of the template is somehow attached to the sent item.  The retention policy sees the age of the item and immediately deletes the email.